# Multiple amp-lists on one page

Tags: json, amp-html, amp-list, amp-bind

I am trying to implement multiple amp-lists with pagination on one AMP page.
Here is my amp-lists HTML:

```
<amp-list layout="fixed-height" height="450" src="/wp-json/posts/v2/category/events/1" data-amp-bind-src="'/wp-json/posts/v2/category/events/' + events_pageNumber" binding="no" single-item="" reset-on-refresh="" i-amphtml-layout="fixed-height" i-amphtml-binding="">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
        <p class="info">Page {{currentPage}} of {{pageCount}}</p>                         
        <div class="items">
            {{#posts}}
                <div class="item">
                    strong class="title">{{title}}</strong>
                </div>
            {{/posts}}
        </div>
    </template>
    <div>
        <p class="info">Page 1 of 2</p>                       
        <div class="items">
            <div class="item">
                <strong class="title">Stay up-to-date with the one latest tech trends</strong>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</amp-list>
<div class="navigation">
    <button class="prev" data-amp-bind-hidden="events_pageNumber < 2" on="tap: AMP.setState({ events_pageNumber: events_pageNumber - 1 })" i-amphtml-binding="">Previous</button>
    <button class="next" data-amp-bind-hidden="events_page ? events_pageNumber >= events_page.items.pageCount : false" on="tap: AMP.setState({ events_pageNumber: events_pageNumber ? events_pageNumber + 1 : 2 })" i-amphtml-binding="" hidden="">Next</button>
</div>
<amp-state id="events_page" src="/wp-json/posts/v2/category/events/1" data-amp-bind-src="'/wp-json/posts/v2/category/events/' + events_pageNumber" i-amphtml-layout="container" i-amphtml-binding="" hidden="" aria-hidden="true"></amp-state>


<amp-list layout="fixed-height" height="450" src="/wp-json/posts/v2/category/news/1" data-amp-bind-src="'/wp-json/posts/v2/category/news/' + news_pageNumber" binding="no" single-item="" reset-on-refresh="" i-amphtml-layout="fixed-height" i-amphtml-binding="">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
        <p class="info">Page {{currentPage}} of {{pageCount}}</p>                         
        <div class="items">
            {{#posts}}
                <div class="item">
                    strong class="title">{{title}}</strong>
                </div>
            {{/posts}}
        </div>
    </template>
    <div>
        <p class="info">Page 1 of 2</p>                       
        <div class="items">
            <div class="item">
                <strong class="title">Stay up-to-date with the one latest tech trends</strong>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</amp-list>
<div class="navigation">
    <button class="prev" hidden="" data-amp-bind-hidden="news_pageNumber < 2" on="tap: AMP.setState({ news_pageNumber: news_pageNumber - 1 })" i-amphtml-binding="">Previous</button>
    <button class="next" data-amp-bind-hidden="news_page ? news_pageNumber >= news_page.items.pageCount : false" on="tap: AMP.setState({ news_pageNumber: news_pageNumber ? news_pageNumber + 1 : 2 })" i-amphtml-binding="">Next</button>
</div>
<amp-state id="news_page" src="/wp-json/posts/v2/category/news/1" data-amp-bind-src="'/wp-json/posts/v2/category/news/' + news_pageNumber" i-amphtml-layout="container" i-amphtml-binding="" hidden="" aria-hidden="true"></amp-state>
```

Each list has its own `_pageNumber` and `_page` vars.

The problem is that on changing page by clicking next/previous buttons of one element `[src]` attribute is changed for all elements (last digit in url changed to `null`). How I can avoid applying setState to all elements?

Comment: use an ID on a list and link to the template.

Comment: @JayGray I've tried that way: `<amp-list template="news-template"></amp-list>` and `<template type="amp-mustache" id="news-template">` unfortunately it didn't work. Also moved `amp-mustache` outside `amp-list`. I think the problem might be in AMP `on tap setState` event. Maybe there is a way to link event to `<amp-state>` element?

Comment: separate IDs (one for each list)?

Comment: Yes, `#news-template` for one element and `#events-template` for another one...

Comment: Where did this come from: `i-amphtml-binding`? Did you use `amp-optimizer`? Or are you copying from `page source` of a production page? Those elements should not be in your source code.

Comment: That's `page source`  because my html is in php and yes it's converted by  AMP optimizer.   Originally - `binding="no" single-item reset-on-refresh`

Comment: I'm not seeing the error. Suggest you open an issue on `amp.dev` and provide **full** source code (without full source your issue will be ignored). The AMP developers are responsive when they are presented with a reproducible issue.